Table is confusing: Discovery of tRNA publication
I'm a student and kinda new to reading papers; currently trying to read A SOLUBLE RIBONUCLEIC ACID INTERMEDIATE IN PROTEIN SYNTHESIS!
Everything else I can parse together given what we now know about tRNA role in translation. However, Table II (Table 2) confuses me.
If they start with the same amount of prelabeled C14, why do we see different total counts in each row?
My biggest question is that we see radioactivity transfer to the protein fraction in the "complete system minus generating system" conditions, but not under "complete system minus generating system with 5xGTP" ?? Wouldn't that undermine the idea that GTP is necessary for translation?
Image attached below!


Welcome Cytos. It would be helpful if you transcribed your notes next to the table so that it is more readable.

As you are probably aware, Hoagland has written a detailed and readable account of his role, and that of the Zamecnik lab,  in the discovery of tRNA (Celebrating complementarity), together with a renowned autobiographical account (Toward the Habit of Truth – A Life in Science)
